# Mockjax via a function and data

Tags: mockjax

In mockjax you can use a function to return a different response according to the request data type, like so:

```
$.mockjax(function(settings) {
    if ( settings.dataType == 'json' ) {
         return {
             dataType: 'json',
             proxy: 'test.json'
         };
    }
    return false;
});
```

Is there a way to do the same thing according to the data sent via the request?
This is the only way I can find so far:

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/',
    data: { variable: 0 },
    proxy: 'test.json'
});
```

What I want to do is change the proxy to a different file if `variable > 0`.

So for example is there a way to parse:

```
data: { variable: <0 }
```

or similar?

Comment: Same problem here. sidonaldson, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but you should be able to investigate the `settings.data` property for that:

```
$.mockjax(function(settings) {
    var proxyFile = 'test.json'; // a default proxy?

    if ( settings.data.variable > 0 ) {
        proxyFile = 'test-greater-than-zero.json'
    }

    return {
        proxy: proxyFile
    };
});
```

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for but I'll mark yours as the answer so you get some points

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If not, I'd be happy to try to help... maybe you could submit a Github issue if there is something you think is missing.

Comment: This seems to pick up on all ajax calls after this; is there a way to only pick up on specific URLs?

Comment: No, but you can inspect the `settings.url` to match specific URLs. Returning a falsy value (like `undefined`) results in no mock.